# What might be a good way to fix this damaged drywall(?)?

Tags: drywall, walls, paint, patching-drywall

I had 2 3M Command hooks on my wall. When I was removing the hooks, I damaged the wall, as you can see in the photos below. I wonder what might be an easy/good way to patch the damage. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The easiest is pollyfiller the holes (remove excess paper) (nice and smooth), let it dry, use a 600 sand paper with a plank or flat surface thing, sand it down smooth so its flush with the pain, repaint the wall with the same paint or the room if using different paint. Nobody will notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one layer of paper has separated from the other. The paper surrounding the tearout has loose flaps of paper around it too.

Remove all loose paper and give a tight skim coat or two of paste spackle, sand smooth, prime and paint.

[image: Wall fix]

You will be wise to get a 4" drywall knife to help in this. The little 1" knife that is considered a putty knife are good for nail holes and window glazing. Check out a YouTube tutorial on [drywall paper tear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFKQVpJscrs) repair

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a good way to match the color of the paint?

Comment: If you can release the portion of the wall that is still on the hooks without damaging the surface anymore, that will give a good color to take to a paint store and have the color computer matched. There is another way too, see the  edited answer. I used your picture to help with the answer on color matching

Answer (score 0):

*I misinterpreted the photos.  On my small monitor set for night mode, it looked like a couple holes all the way through the sheetrock.  This answer explains how to patch holes in the sheetrock:*

---

Which do you want?

## Good

Cut a rectangular section out of the wall which includes both holes.  It is easier if both the left side and the right side of the hole extends over studs at least a little (more is okay).  The straighter you cut the edges, the less hassle it will be to patch.  Buy a piece of [patch sheetrock](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sheetrock-5-8-in-x-2-ft-x-2-ft-Gypsum-Patching-Panel-Drywall-141125/205721081) of the *same* thickness as the wall.  If you are in the U.S., it will be 3/8 inch, 1/2 inch, or 5/8 inch thick.  Cut the patch sheetrock to about 1/8 inch smaller than the hole so that there is 1/16 or gap on each edge.  (Give yourself several chances to fit by cutting the patch from a corner.)

The existing sheetrock has several layers of material on its bare sheetrock:  texture, primer, and *X* layers of paint.  Ideally the new sheetrock should be flush with the original bare sheetrock, so it will seem recessed a millimetre or two.  It is very easy to have it not in far enough causing a prominent section of wall when done.

Fasten the patch into place using construction glue or sheetrock screws.  Apply [joint compound](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Westpac-Materials-3-1-2-Qt-All-Purpose-Pre-Mixed-Joint-Compound-18680H/100320408?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-205721081-_-100320408-_-N) to the edges.  Work it lightly and let cure.  Sand lightly for smoothness.

Texture either with a [texturing spray product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Homax-20-oz-Wall-Orange-Peel-Low-Odor-Water-Based-Spray-Texture-4092-06/100154309), or by thinning two tablespoons of joint compound with like 1/4 teaspoon of water (to form cake batter consistency) and use a paint brush to splatter it on the patched area.  Don't worry about mistakes.  It is easily wiped off within a few minutes if there is too much.  Let dry.  Gently smooth with a damp sponge to match the existing texture.

Paint.

## Easy

If this is in an area not likely to be bumped, install some backing material inside the wall:  duct tape, 1x3 wood or wider, etc.  Wood will be easier to make work because it can be screwed to the sheetrock from the front.  Be careful not to split it when fastening.

Then use some joint compound or spackle and fill it in.  That is more depth than it is usually used for so shrinkage will be significant.  So do it in several layers filling about half of the remaining depth with each layer.

After it cures, texture (or not) and paint as above.

Comment: You would cut a large hole and apply all that work to fix a simple tear in the surface paper of the drywall??

Comment: @MichaelKaras:  Oh!  I thought there were holes in the sheetrock.  Now that I look at the photos, I see you are right and it is simply marred surface.